# How to trigger levolutions in multiplayer?

Tags: battlefield-4

The levolution were touted as the big thing in BF4, but the only levolutions I have seen in action are in the floodzone map and the iconic siege of shanghai skyscraper demolition.

What I would like to know is how to trigger levolutions in the other maps, as I'd like to see their effects on the playing field.

Comment: Be carefull of the siege of shanghai, if you destroy the center tower. Most of the time half of the people on the server crashes out of the game.

Comment: Yeah, other levolutions can cause that as well, like the crashing ship in Paracel Storm, or the cracking street in Dawnbreaker.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Golmud Railway**: There is a mobile flag on a train, that drives (slowly) to the current owners base. There are also somewhat hidden explosives scattered about the map. They can be triggered by a computer nearby. The explosions leave big holes, providing some cover.

**Hainan Resort**: There are oil puddles which can be set aflame, producing a smokescreen for cover. You can also destroy the 2 wings of the hotel. Destroy the first two ground floors on either the left or right side to demolish the left or right side of the building.

**Zavod 311**: You can destroy the chimney of the factory via a terminal within the factory. The terminal starts a timer (3 minutes, I think).

**Operation Locker**: Many locker doors can be closed, potentially hindering enemy movement. The watchtower in the middle of the map can also be destroyed.

**Dawnbreaker**: There are 2 gas pipeline stations, which you can activate. Once activated, the main streets cracks open and the bridge collapses.

**Lancang Dam**: Shoot at the damn (RPG, Tank) and it starts to crumble, which causes debris to fly around the map. Electricity also fails, which causes the buildings to go dark.

**Paracel Storm**: The map starts sunny and calm, but a storm is coming. Waves start to get higher and flying gets more difficult. There is a ship that crashed into a wind turbine. Once the storm hits, there are cracks that appear in the turbine base. You need to shoot at that, to break the ship free. The ship then floats to the flagpoint C (the insel), causing huge destruction to it.

**Rogue Transmission**: You can destroy the antenna by shooting at the 10 supporting steel ropes.

Comment: In stuff like Paracel Storm and Hainan Resort, you can fully destroy the houses around some points aswell.

Comment: Also, these are only the big levolution events. Levolution is considered the mechanics that makes the maps mostly destructible and dynamic.

Shooting that electric box that makes a room go dark, blowing up a wall to create a new flanking route, making a building crumble and kill the squad hiding in it. Closing the gates at the mall. These all fall under the term levolution.

Comment: RE: Paracel Storm. Once the storm hits, there are cracks that appear in the turbine base. You need to shoot at that, not the boat.

Comment: @tombull89 - added it to the answer.

Comment: Could be more specific on how to destroy the two wings of the hotel on Hainan Resort?

Comment: @Sentry - It's in the answer now.